# Make <aside> elements fill 100% width of the parent container

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website and am willing to achieve the following layout. I would greatly appreciate if you could guide me to the working solution.

In the header of a page there is:

1. a logo on the left (`<a>` tag)
2. 2 widgets (`<aside>` tags) in a `<div>`

**I need these 2 widgets to take up all the remaining width** (all 100% except for the logo width).

How do I do this with CSS? If there is no way to do it without modifying HTML, then what (and how) would you suggest to change? Responsiveness is not a priority #1, however the webpage itself is responsive.

I understand there are many possible solutions, but please do not suggest JavaScript solutions or HTML changes that make use of tables.

Meanwhile I will try to prepare a code snippet to avoid possible misunderstanding ...

Comment: do you know the width of the logo/will it ever change?

Comment: also should the `<aside>`s each be 50% of the remaining width?

Comment: @willanderson Yes, the size of the logo is fixed: 130x124px

Comment: @willanderson No, the sizes of `<aside>` are different. However, I believe I may be able to fix the size of the rightmost `<aside>`. In this case I want the first (left) `<aside>` to fill all the remaining space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it:

1. Give `header` `overflow:hidden` so its height will wrap floated elements (or you could use a clearfix)
2. Make the `header` have `padding-left` the same width as the logo. Make
   the logo `float:left` with a negative `margin-left` the same width as the
   logo.  This will fill the `padding-left` of the `header` with the
   logo.
3. Make the `header` have `padding-right` the same width as the 2nd
   `<aside>`. Make the 2nd `<aside>` `float:right` with a negative
   `margin-right` the same width as the 2nd `<aside>`.  This will fill the
   `padding-right` of the `header` with the 2nd `<aside>`.
4. Lastly, give the 1st `<aside>` `float:left` and `width:100%`.  Boom - you're done!

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7gJwk/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much, willanderson! I seems to work very well. Perhaps the _magical_ part about this solution is the use of `overflow: hidden` :)
One last (optional) thing: is there an easy way to make this `<aside>` elements fill 100% height?

Comment: not dynamically, however if they should always be the same height of the logo you could just set `aside { height:124px; }`

Comment: other possibility which I didn't suggest since you want to avoid tables is using `display:table`/`display:table-cell` to use the behavior of `tables` without actually using them. see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/AWgsj/1/